# Sending data in GET request Python

Tags: python-3.x, http, get, python-requests

I know that it is not an advisable solution to use GET however I am not in control of how this server works and have very little experience with requests.

I'm looking to add a dictionary via a GET request and was told that the server had been set up to accept this but I'm not sure how that works. I have tried using

```
import requests
r = request.get('www.url.com', data = 'foo:bar')
```

but this leaves the webpage unaltered, any ideas?

Comment: Could you include the url?

Answer (score 1):

To use request-body with a get request, you must override the post method. e.g.

```
    request_header={
            'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'GET' 
        }
    response = requests.post(request_uri, request_body, headers=request_header)
```

Answer (score 1):

For people stumbling hare after all these years, try this maybe

```
import requests
r = request.get("www.url.com", params={"foo": "bar"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use requests like this pass the the data in the data field of the requests

```
requests.get(url, headers=head, data=json.dumps({"user_id": 436186}))
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are using the wrong parameters for the get request. The doc for `requests.get()` is [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.get).

- You should use `params` instead of `data` as the parameter.
- You are missing the `http` in the url.

The following should work:

```py
import requests

r = request.get('http://www.url.com', params = {'foo': 'bar'})

print(r.content)
```

The actual request can be inspected via `r.request.url`, it should be like this:

> http://www.url.com?foo=bar

Comment: import requests, requeST.get check code please.

Answer (score -2):

If you're not sure about how the server works, you should send a POST request, like so:

```py
import requests

data = {'name', 'value'}

requests.post('http://www.example.com', data=data)
```

If you absolutely need to send data with a GET request, make sure that data is in a **dictionary** and instead pass information with *params* keyword.

You may find helpful the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)